# Задача с перечислениями

Tags: c++

Постановка задачи: 
Напишите программу, которая сначала по первой букве должности, введен- ной пользователем, определяет соответствующее значение переменной, помещает это значение в переменную типа etype, а затем выводит полностью название должности, первую букву которой ввел пользователь. Взаимодействие программы с пользователем может выглядеть следующим образом:  Введите первую букву должности  (laborer, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, researcher); a  полное название должности: accountant

Как я это реализовал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
enum etype { laborer, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, researcher 
};
int main()
{
   char ch;
   etype word;
   cout << "Enter first letter posts \n";
   cout << "(laborer, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, 
   researcher); ";
   ch = _getche();
   switch (ch)
   {
   case 'l': word = laborer; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << endl; 
   break;
   case 's': word = secretary; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << endl; 
   break;
   case 'm': word = manager; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << endl; 
   break;
   case 'a': word = accountant; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << 
   endl; break;
   case 'e': word = executive; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << endl; 
   break;
   case 'r': word = researcher; cout << "\nFull name post: " << word << 
   endl; break;
   default: cout << "\nThe post not found!";  break;
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Но как и ожидаемо, выводятся цифры, вместо названий. Но я не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы выводились названия. В голову приходит только прописывать их вручную в cout в кавычках...

Comment: Скажите, а тип etype у Вас в задании такой или на него не  накладывается ограничений?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, именно такой.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вообще так длинно? Можно и без этого `switch`... Вот, примерно так (просто наброски! чтоб понять идею, а не чтоб броситься компилировать как есть...)

```
enum etype
{
    laborer = 0, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, researcher
};

const char firstLetters[] = "lsmaer";
const char * position[] = {
    "laborer", "secretary", "manager", "accountant", "executive", "researcher"
};

...

ch = _getche();

// Ищем, есть ли введенная буква среди первых букв
char * who = strchr("lsmaer",ch);
// если нет - сообщаем об ошибке, и идем заново.
if (who == 0) cout << "Wrong input\n"; // И к началу цикла ввода

// Какая буква по счету - та и профессия (enum - это же просто число)
word = who - firstLetters;
// Выводим название профессии
cout << "Position: " << position[word] << "\n";
```

Компилируемый пример.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

enum etype { laborer = 0, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, researcher };

struct Position
{
    etype code;
    char * name;
}
positions[] = {
#define ITEM(x) { x, #x }
    ITEM(laborer),      ITEM(secretary),    ITEM(manager),
    ITEM(accountant),   ITEM(executive),    ITEM(researcher)
};

int main()
{
   Position word;
   cout << "Enter first letter (";
   for(auto pos = begin(positions); pos != end(positions); ++pos)
   {
       if (pos != begin(positions)) cout << ", ";
       cout << pos->name;
   }
   cout << "): ";
   char ch = _getche();
   bool found = false;
   for(auto pos : positions)
       if (pos.name[0] == ch)
       {
           word = pos;  found = true;   break;
       }
   if (found)
       cout << "\n\nFull name is " << word.name << endl;
   else
       cout << "\n\nWrong input\n";
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: три не связанные переменные. ох-ох-ох.допустить ошибку - раз плюнуть.

Comment: @KoVadim Конечно, проще загнать в структуру и не мучиться, но уровень вопроса говорит о том, что может остаться непонятым... Впрочем, пуркуа бы и не па? сейчас набросаю...

Comment: @KoVadim Есть идеи, как извлечь из перечисления все наименования и воткнуть их в массив? а то все равно каждая из профессий вводится дважды... но я что-то с этим навскидку справиться не могу.

Comment: Есть как минимум 4 способа: X-macros, Qt enums, свой парсер, с++20 (или все таки 17). Но вряд ли они нужны автору вопроса.